# How to set Maximum and Minimum Time Limit for TimePickerDialog for the user to choose within a certain Hour Range?

Tags: android

I have created a normal TimePickerDialog that takes time input from user. But I want to change this so that it only accepts the hour of time within a minimum and maximum hour value. And i want to set the minimum and maximum value dynamically(sent through arguments when it is created or some other way)

```
public class TimePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public static final String EXTRA_TIME = "com.android.XYZ.time";


private static final String ARG_TIME = "time";

private TimePicker mTimePicker;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_time, null);

    mTimePicker = (TimePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_time_picker);


    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).
            setView(v).
            setTitle("Choose a time").
            setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
                        int getHour = mTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
                        int getMinute = mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
                        int getSecond = 0;

                        Time time = new Time(getHour,getMinute,getSecond);

                        //Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
                        sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, time);
                    } else{
                        int getHour = mTimePicker.getHour();
                        int getMinute = mTimePicker.getMinute();
                        int getSecond = 0;

                        Time time = new Time(getHour,getMinute,getSecond);

                        //Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
                        sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, time);

                    }

                }
            }).create();

}


/**
 * To send the chosen time result to Required class thorough intent
 * @param resultCode
 * @param time
 */
private void sendResult(int resultCode, Time time){
    if(getTargetFragment() == null){
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TIME, time);

    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(),resultCode,intent);
}


/**
 * Creating new instance of Time Picker
 * @param time
 * @return
 */
public static TimePickerDialogFragment newInstance(Time time){
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ARG_TIME, time);

    TimePickerDialogFragment fragment = new TimePickerDialogFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a TimeChangedListener and override its `onTimeChanged` method to set the hour to the closest allowed hour using `setHour`.

For example this will force the selected hour to be between 12(12pm) and 15(3pm):

```
mTimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            if(hourOfDay < 12) {
                timePicker.setHour(12);
            }
            else if(hourOfDay > 15) {
                timePicker.setHour(15);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, for anyone googling this error i also made change in argument of new Instance of dialog                                                                          public static TimePickerDialogFragment newInstance(Time time,int requestCode){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_TIME, time);
        args.putInt(REQUEST_CODE,requestCode);
        TimePickerDialogFragment fragment = new TimePickerDialogFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }